# python sort strings with leading numbers alphabetically

Tags: python, string, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I have a list of filenames, each of them beginning with a leading number:

```
10_file
11_file
1_file
20_file
21_file
2_file ...
```

I need to put it in this order:

```
1_file
10_file
11_file
2_file
21_file
22_file ...
```

If they were just numbers as strings ('1') without the underscore I could sort them with sorted(). I have tried different sort-methods with different key-attributes, also the module "natsort", but with no result. Do I have to write my own algorithm for this? Maybe I could extract the leading numbers and use them for sorting?

UPDATED desired list to correct listing

Comment: what is the maximum number before the filenames?

Comment: Depends. Up to 120.

Comment: ok, and do all the filenames actually end with `_file` ?

Comment: No, thats different strings with different characters. But in every case after the leading number there is an underscore.

Comment: Can you explain why `11_file` and `12_file` after `2_file` in your desired sorted order?

Comment: Ups, mistake. Correct desired order is of coures [see updated post above].

Comment: are there duplicate numbers?

Comment: No, no duplicate numbers.

Comment: –1  Where did `20_file` from the input go?  Where did `22_file` in the output appear from?  If there was `100_file` in the input, where should it appear in the output?

Comment: Actually –6 because I've un-upvoted and downvoted, please clarify the 'alphabetical' requirement.

Comment: So far I unterstand "alphabetical order of numbers as strings" numbers are sorted like: 1,10,11,2,20,21,22,3,30, and so on. This is what I need. Where goes the 100 in this order? Its like 1,10,100,2, etc. This is actually not what I want. So alphabetical string sorting is not the best method here. Therefore the title of my question is misleading, true. For my real usecase I can use alphabetically sorting nevertheless. Remains the question how to sort numbers as strings, where for example 100 occurs. Wanted order would be 1,10,2,100

Comment: @wim Desired result was not completely correct. Correct result is 1,10,11,2,20, 21,100, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorting, splitting and list comprehensions work well here.

```
lst = ['10_file', '11_file', '1_file', '20_file', '21_file', '2_file']

lst_split = ['_'.join(x) for x in sorted(i.split('_') for i in lst)]

# ['1_file', '10_file', '11_file', '2_file', '20_file', '21_file']
```

Comment: Hmm, I find the key one easier to read. Partially because it's so much shorter. And how did you measure this? For me your way is *slower* (as I expected): https://ideone.com/GUcVhW

Comment: ... and shorter version I can't include in that benchmark because of its side effect: `lst.sort(key=lambda s: s.split('_'))`

Comment: @StefanPochmann, I used `%timeit` versus Ajax1234's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Edited with what the OP really wanted:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> lst = ['10_file', '11_file', '1_file', '20_file', '21_file', '2_file']
>>> sorted(lst, key=partial(str.split, sep='_', maxsplit=1))
['1_file', '10_file', '11_file', '2_file', '20_file', '21_file']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
flist = ['10_file',
        '11_file',
        '1_file',
        '20_file',
        '21_file',
        '2_file']

tempdict = {}

for item in flist:
    num = item.split('_')[0]
    tempdict[num] = item

output = []

# for truly numeric sorting
#for k in sorted([int(k) for k in tempdict.keys()]):
    #output.append(tempdict[str(k)])

# for alphabetical sorting:
for k in sorted(tempdict.keys()):
    output.append(tempdict[k])

print('\n'.join(output))
```

**Result**

```
1_file
10_file
11_file
2_file
20_file
21_file
```

Comment: Just a note: `print("")` works in Python2 and Python3. `print ""` only works in Python2

Comment: I downvoted because this obliterates any duplicate numbers.

Comment: @JacobIRR This works. Seems to be the right way to solution. I have to figure out to implement in my surrounding (with first try on the real list I got error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. But with your list it works.

Comment: you can prevent that Value error by changing `num, name = item.split('_')` to `num, name = item.split('_')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The simple way. Just extract the digits and then sort it as string:

`sorted(l, key=lambda s: s.split("_")[0] )`

That's all you need... try:

```
l=['2_file', '10_file', '11_file', '1_file', '20_file', '21_file']
print "\n".join(sorted(l, key=lambda s: s.split("_")[0] ))
1_file
10_file
11_file
2_file
20_file
21_file
```